# Delay super.onbackpressed in android

Tags: android, quit

I made a script which detects if there's internet connection:

```
    public static boolean isOnline() {
    try {
        InetAddress.getByName("google.hu").isReachable(3);
        return true;
    } catch (UnknownHostException e){
        return false;
    } catch (IOException e){
        return false;
    }
}
```

If there's no internet the app will warn the user and the quit! But how to delay super.onBackPressed for 20 seconds? :)

```
    this.toast1 = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
    toast1.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
    toast1.setDuration(20000);
    toast1.setView(layout);
    toast1.show();
    super.onBackPressed();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Thread delayThread= new Thread(new Runnable()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void run()
                        {
                            try
                {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                }
            catch (InterruptedException e)
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                            activityInstance.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
                                {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run()
                                        {
                                            super.onBackPressed();
                                        }
                                });
                        }
                });
            delayThread.start();
```

Comment: `d.start()` should be `delayThread.start()`. Of course Android 4.0 supports `Thread`, why do you think it doesn't? Also, this thread sleeps for 1 second not 20, so you should use `Thread.sleep(20000)`. And you don't want to call `super.onBackPressed()`, you should just call `finish()` on the activity.

Comment: Guys d.start() was a typo mistake . please forgive me for that (wink)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest is to create a `Handler` in `onCreate()`and use [`postDelayed()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) with a `Runnable` that calls `super.onBackPressed()`